# WAV to AIF conversion - difference between recorded AIF

Tags: audio, endianness, chunks

In audio terms there is no difference between AIF and WAV because they're both uncompressed audio. The only difference is the byte order (endianness).

My question is, can any software tell the difference between an AIF that is recorded as such and an AIF that was recorded WAV and converted?  I've looked at a hex editor and there appears to be a difference in the chunks - the recorded AIF has more empty space in the COMM and SSND chunks, it would seem.

Is there a reason for this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> *"...the recorded AIF has more empty space in the COMM and SSND chunks, it would seem."*

That might be a problem with the specific recorder you use.

In general there is **no size difference** in the uncompressed PCM data. I've tested  a 10-second AAC file converted into WAVE and also into AIFF, result is **both formats** have the PCM data at `1572864` bytes long.

Also explain *`"more empty space in the COMM and SSND chunks"`* since...

- COMM only holds 10 bytes worth of metadata, but in WAV file there'll be up to 84 bytes for metadata.
- SSND is 16 bytes followed by PCM data, in `.wav` the DATA chunk is 8 bytes followed by PCM.

Comment: Thanks for you answer VC.One. This is referring to viewing the file in a hex reader. 
It would seem that it could be program specific but I viewed an AIFF file that was recorded as AIFF, using https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/.  
You have to scroll down a good few times to get from the COMM chunk before the SSND chuck appears.  In a converted file - recorded as WAV, exported as AIFF - there are fewer empty lines that show up on the hex reader.  I was just wondering if this was significant